# Definition of a hyperbolic map

Tags: dynamical-systems

In the field of dynamical systems, a hyperbolic map $T: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined in a few equivalent ways. [One](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicMap.html) of them is: T is hyperbolic iff there exists eigenvalues of T with modulus not equal to 1, and there are eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda_1|>1$ and $|\lambda_2|<1$. Furthermore, mathworld wolfram suggests that this means that we can split such  a map into a direct sum of generalized eigenspaces.

But the reals are not algebraically closed. This means that any map with a rotational component could possibly be hyperbolic as long as it has a direction in which in expands and another in which it contracts, yet such a map doesn't decompose into generalized eigenspaces.

Should we not be working over the complex field instead for this theory to work out properly?

Comment: say a map on $\mathbb{R}^4$. One expansion direction, one contraction direction, and two involved in rotation

Comment: The proper way (and common way in good books in dynamics) is to write $\mathbb C^n$ as a direct sum of generalized eigenspaces and then intersecting with $\mathbb R^n$ (think of it as $\mathbb C^n=\mathbb R^n\oplus\mathbb R^n$). Since the map is real, the intersection goes to itself and thus is invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the standard definition is, that a linear map $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called *hyperbolic* if $T$ is invertible (sometimes this is omitted) and has no eigenvalue of absolute value $1$. For the decomposition into $A$-invariant subspaces over the real numbers see Theorem 1.1 [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=Mw-kxEJREnwC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=hyperbolic+map+eigenvalue+of+modulus+not+1+eigenspace&source=bl&ots=CMf8ap0U-D&sig=zrRJfOHcPhbRvBc7VKi7xjJX4f8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ0eH7sr_aAhWR6aQKHQwICxUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=hyperbolic%20map%20eigenvalue%20of%20modulus%20not%201%20eigenspace&f=false). The statement of the Theorem does not refer to (generalised) eigenspaces, and is correct. The remark afterwards with the eigenspaces is not correct.

Comment: Am I correct to say that although we are working over real vector spaces, we should here consider eigenvalues which are possibly complex?

Comment: Actually it doesn't, the eigenvalues may not be real. It is a quite common mistake by people outside dynamics. The soution is simple: you only need to "intersect" the root spaces with $\mathbb R^n$. By the way, the book that you mention makes the same mistake (although their theorem is correct, as I note above).

Comment: @JohnB The Theorem does not speak of generalised eigenspaces, just of $A$-invariant spaces. This should be no problem, right?

Comment: Right, I'm referring to the text after the theorem. The "are easily identified" is the mistake.

Comment: It is not that they are not precise, it is a serious mistake.

Comment: I think they are just sloppy, but yes, it doesn't look good.